# Vue2 Watcher issue with DOM manipulation

Tags: vue.js

I am using watcher to be able to run certiain UI changes after an async operation where I have a large array.

as follows:

#### getting a true/false response on files that are loaded

```
computed: {
            checkAssignmentFilesAreLoaded: function () {
                return this.$store.state.assFilesLoaded
            },
```

#### inside watch's computed function reference I am running a function to remove an element from an array that has the class `cutOff`

```
watch: {
            checkAssignmentFilesAreLoaded() {
            const check = $('.cutOff')
            const elem = document.getElementsByClassName("cutOff");
            console.log('test',elem, check);
            }
        },
```

As you can see i've tried different things, I also thought that this would require some sort of DOM update so I went on and ran `$forceUpdate()`, which also didn't provide a solution.
tried with vanilla and also with jquery, jquery doesn't return any element back and `elem` returns  it via HTMLCollection, yet still **BOTH do not respond to any manipulations**.

-Jquery is loaded before vue and work perfect across the app, only with this issue with watcher, this happens.

I just need to append a paragraph in cutOff. What would you guys think about this?

> #### edit: it's an async issue:

```
setTimeout(function(){
                    const cutOff = $('.cutOff')
                    cutOff.append('<div class="cutOff__text">show </div>')
                });
```

this works, yet extremely wrong to do. Looking for a Vue framework solution for answer, i'll accept the answer if it works well, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use jQuery for this part, what I would do is something like this:

```
<template>
    ...
    <div class="cutOff__text" v-show="checkAssignmentFilesAreLoaded">show</div>
    ...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        ...
        computed: {
            checkAssignmentFilesAreLoaded: function () {
                return this.$store.state.assFilesLoaded
            },
        }
        ...
    }
</script>
```

and of course at checkAssignmentFilesAreLoaded you can return false or null or that is already happening, and if that function returns different it will show the div